# Trying to find remainder using an integer and a double

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    double amount;
    int toonie = 2;
    double remainder;
    printf("Change Maker Machine\n");
    printf("====================\n");
    printf("Enter dollars and cents amount to convert to coins: $");
    scanf("%lf", &amount);

    toonie = amount / 2;
    remainder = amount % 2;

    printf("%ld is the amount of toonies you need", toonie);
    printf("%lf is the remainder for your change", remainder);




    return 0;
}
```

I am writing a basic program in which I take a user's input as to how much money they have and I return how many toonies I can give for that amount. I also want to display the remainder which cannot be given from toonies. When I compile this on VSStudio I get errors saying the following:

1. expression must have integral type
2. return value ignored: 'scanf'
3. '=' conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
4. '%': illegal, left operand has type 'double'

Comment: You know the dollar value of `toonies`, so you can simply subtract that from `amount`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use integer math for floating point.

Instead:

```
double d = 2;
double remainder = fmod(amount , d);
double toonie = (amount - remainder)/d;
```

---

Yet better to use integer math for money.

```
#include <math.h>
...

if (scanf("%lf", &amount) == 1) {
  long amount_in_cents == lround(amount * 100.0);

  long toonie = amount_in_cents / 200;
  int remainder_in_cents = amount_in_cents % 200;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I would steer them away from floating-point entirely, not introduce `fmod`. It’s going to break when they tried `fmod(x, .05)` and so on.

Comment: @EricPostpischil With the anticipated C23 with decimal FP, looks like there will be a whole new set of issues.  Then `fmodd64(x, 0.05)` will be fine.  With all the questions about IEEE binary FP layout, trying to explain the 2 decimal layouts will be an endless task.  Maybe it is complicated enough so folks will refrain from bit dibbling decimal FP and stick with library functions - doubt it though.